# Splice not splicing from the index its being given?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

Working in vue here, specifically vuex although it's likely a vanilla js problem. I've got a cart setup that pushes from a product list to a shopping cart on button press, but I cannot get deleting from the cart to work. Here's my approach;

The child calling the action from a button;

```
<b-button @click="removeItem" variant="primary">Remove from Cart</b-button>

data() {
    return {
        singleCart: this.items,
    };
},
methods: {
    removeItem() {
        this.$store.dispatch("DELETE_CART_ITEM", this.singleCart.item_id);
    },
},
```

And the logic in my vuex store;

```
const actions = {
    ADD_TO_CART: (context, payload) => {
        context.commit('MUTATE_CART', payload)
    },
    DELETE_CART_ITEM: (context, payload) => {
        context.commit('DELETE_FROM_CART', payload)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    MUTATE_CART: (state, item) => {
        state.cart.push(item)
    },
    DELETE_FROM_CART: (state, payload) => {
        //filter the array for the item id, then splice it?

        console.log(payload)

        var index = state.cart.findIndex(item => item.item_id === payload)

        console.log(index)

        console.log(typeof index)

        state.cart.splice(index, 1)
    }
}
```

All my logging shows the correct payload, and the correct index of the item in the cart, but when the splicing happens, It's removing the last item on the list, even though its being passed a starting index.

For example if I have 3 items in the cart, and I want to remove the second, it finds the proper index, 1 in such case, logs it to be sure, then for whatever reason splice deletes the last item on the list. Why? And what would I do to fix this?

SOLUTION: Turns out I was just confused on how I should call my getter data in the end, the solution was in the parent component that loops over the shopping cart items and using a computed property to get it instead as such;

```
<div v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id">
<cartProduct :items="item" />
</div>

computed: {
    cart() {
        return this.$store.getters.GET_CART 
    }
},
```

And thus was reactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird Vue caveat. Below is an example of what will not work in this case.

```
DELETE_FROM_CART: (state, payload) => {
        var index = state.cart.findIndex(item => item.item_id === payload);
        var dummy = state.cart.slice();
        dummy.splice(index, 1);
        state.cart = dummy;
    }
```

Comment: Sadly I've already tried that exact line, the correct payload is logged, and the mutation is called but the cart doesn't update to a new array for some reason. Edit: upon giving the state a log, the logged array is in fact changed, but just doesn't update the component vue.

Comment: That's because of how Vue works--I'll update the post so it does work

Comment: Vue doesn't always update in cases like these. `Vue.set` lets it know, so it does update. Try this.

Comment: Not entirely a vanilla JS problem, I guess.

Comment: After changing to Vue.set the component still isn't updating re-actively

Comment: Maybe try the new answer?

Comment: Still no reaction. Your logic has been correct every time based on what the console is giving me, Vue just can't seem to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223374/discussion-between-alexh-and-katwatsu).

Comment: I had a similar problem in which I had an array of Asset objects, which each asset having a `products` array. The `splice()` method worked while working directly with Vue components but when running it in a Jest Test case, it would not update the array at all!. I ended up using `filter()` instead. Array methods generally cause Vuex to trigger changes but I guess this `products` array was too deeply nested or something. Note: use filter only if your data set is relatively small